# Docker Compose yaml global config

Tags: docker-compose

Is there a way to specify a global configuration that will apply for all services in a docker-compose.yml file? Eg:

```yaml
glorious-global-settings-for-all-services:
   working_dir: /services

services:
   service-1:
      ...
   service-2:
      ...
```

I've tried looking far and wide, but Google mostly wants to tell me about how to OVERRIDE docker-compose.yaml:s, of which the question in question is not about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [docker-compose fragments doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/10-fragments/), you can use YAML fragments to do some kind of global configuration for your services.

Here's an example:

```yaml
version: "3"

x-global_config: &GLOBAL_CONFIG
    working_dir: /services

services:
  service-1:
    image: traefik/whoami
    <<: *GLOBAL_CONFIG

  service-2:
    image: traefik/whoami
    <<: *GLOBAL_CONFIG
```

`docker compose` would yield a configuration like this:

```
$ docker compose config
name: fragment-example
services:
  service-1:
    image: traefik/whoami
    networks:
      default: null
    working_dir: /services
  service-2:
    image: traefik/whoami
    networks:
      default: null
    working_dir: /services
networks:
  default:
    name: fragment-example_default
x-global_config:
  working_dir: /services
```